# Data synchronization in a Chrome packaged app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, synchronization, xmlhttprequest, breeze, google-chrome-app

In my pursuit to write a Chrome packaged app, I am struggling to get my data synchronized to the app so that it can be used in offline mode.

My data lives on a server and I access it trough a restful service in this case I use.net MVC WebApi

*What I have tried*: Using Breezejs because of the easy offline capabilities ; the problem is that 
window.localStorage 
  is not available in packaged apps, I did tried switching it out for IndexedDB but no luck.

I tried chrome.storage that worked great with the build in sync but it is not a big truck and that is what I need at least a 10tunner.

So my Question; is there a silver bullet that has some XMLHttpRequest implementations, that makes it easier to get data from a restful service, storing it to IndexedDB so that it can be used offline and when going online syncs the changes, that is compatible with packaged apps.

I know I must probably write my own but if someone already went trough all the hoops and complexities of synchronization that can guide me it will be awesome.

Comment: What failed when trying IndexdDB.

Comment: I failed somewhat to implement IndexedDB, but used a indexedDB wrapper [db.js](http://aaronpowell.github.io/db.js/); replaced the localStorage in breeze.debug.js with it. But its not feeling right because changing the api directly is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using the [syncFileSystem API ?](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem.html)

As long as you are happy to sync your data into Google Drive, this api should meet your needs for not implementing sync code yourself and still working offline.

Comment: I also thought of something like that but the thing is that I want to sync the data that is on my server in a sql dB to the indexedDB. The best solution that I got so far is to tweak breezejs to suite my needs but it is not ideal.